# Regular expression to capture hex numbers with odd number of characters

Tags: regex, pcre

I have a list of comma separated hex numbers like below,

```
    aaffd,123,1,d3213,aaa,f
    aaa,dd,1234,d,c
```

And I want a regular expression for pcregrep to match only the lines containing hex numbers where each hex number has odd number of characters.

Should match:

```
    aaffd,123,1,d3213,aaa,f
    1
    2,345,1
```

Should not match:

```
    ad,ad
    1,23,1,333
```

I am trying with this regex
    ([0-9a-f],?|((?:(?:[0-9a-f]{2})+[0-9a-f]),?))+

But it captures unnecessary lines as well. As shown in the link 
https://regex101.com/r/uvJcbD/5

How to capture only the lines containing hex numbers where each hex number has odd number of characters? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the job:

```
^(?=[0-9a-f,]+$)[^,](?:[^,]{2})*(?:,[^,](?:[^,]{2})*)*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/5PML6I/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can match an odd number of characters by repeating zero or more times this range `[a-f0-9]{2}` followed by 1 time that range.

Follow that by repeating the previous pattern zero or more times but preceded by a comma.

`^(?:[a-f0-9]{2})*[a-f0-9](?:,(?:[a-f0-9]{2})*[a-f0-9])*$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gqx8cP/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[a-f0-9]{2}` Match 2 times characters a-f0-9
- `)*`Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `[a-f0-9]` Match characters a-f0-9
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `,` Match comma
  - `(?:`  Non capturing group

    - `[a-f0-9]{2}` Match 2 times characters a-f0-9
  - `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
  - `[a-f0-9]` Match characters a-f0-9
- `)*` Close non capturing group
- `$` End of the string

Comment: Thank you very much! It works for my issue. :)
Thank you for the explanation as well! Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
^(?:\b\w(?:\w\w)*\b,?)*$
```

It matches an unlimited number of *words* containing an odd number of characters. It uses word boundary (`\b`) to detect start and ending of words, and allows an optional comma (to be able to match the last one).

If you want *syntax checking* of the hex characters as well (i.e. only valid hex characters), use

```
^(?:\b[a-f0-9](?:[a-f0-9]{2})*\b,?)*$
```

[See it (the first one) here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Qm6Y9J/1).